# Can't Click "Allow" When Testing Vimeo API OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am new to APIs and have made my first OAuth 2.0 calls to the Vimeo API.

I was able to reach the Vimeo login that allows authorization. However, when I login with my username and password, I am not able to click "allow". I've tried both Postman and Insomnia clients and get the same issue. If I click "Don't Allow" the window simply turns blank. I'm wondering what might be causing this hang-up where I cannot click "Allow" and get back my access token

[Image of Window (Insomnia Client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYRsQ.png).

Please let me know if you need any code or more images in order to troubleshoot.

Thanks from a newbie,
-Josh

Answer (score 0):

Could you open a ticket here, https://vimeo.com/help/contact.

We'll need to triage this with your account info.

Comment: I figured it out. I was incorrectly using the fields in my API clients and the URL that was getting generated was a bit of a mess. All is working as it should now. Thanks!